# If a user has not authenticated himself to a web module in Java EE, what will EJBContext#getCallerPrincipal() return?

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, servlets, ejb, userprincipal

For a *Servlet* to get the `Principal` of a web user, he will call `HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`. According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29), this method will return `null` if the user has not authenticated himself. Makes sense.

If an *enterprise java bean* (EJB) want to get the Principal of a user, he will make a call to  `EJBContext#getCallerPrincipal()`. However, according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getCallerPrincipal%28%29), this method **never returns null**.

### So what does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I sadly cannot refer to any kind of documentation of exactly what happens when `EJBContext#getCallerPrincipal()` is called for a user not authenticated, I did my experiment using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5). It shows that getCallerPrincipal() will indeed return a `Principal`, and that calling *toString()* or *getName()* of this principal both return the string **ANONYMOUS**. That might be good to know!